# Remote Powershell execution of Glassfish asadmin utility fails silently

Tags: java, powershell, glassfish

I'm attempting to create a new Glassfish domain. I'm logged in to machine A and Glassfish is installed on machine B. The command I'm running is:

```
invoke-command -Session $session -scriptblock {Start-Process -FilePath "adadmin" -ArgumentList "create-domain --instanceport 28182 --nopassword=true my_gf_domain_name" -WorkingDirectory D:\Glassfish\4.1.13\bin
```

This does not return an error and I can't see a log anywhere on server B that would give any indication as to why this is failing:

If I login to server B and run:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "adadmin" -ArgumentList "create-domain --instanceport 28182 --nopassword=true my_gf_domain_name" -WorkingDirectory D:\Glassfish\4.1.13\bin
```

The domain "*my_gf_domain_name*" creates fine. A cmd window pops up (with output from the domain create process) in the background when I run the `Start-Process` on machine B. My guess is that this pop-up is possibly causing my problem.

Comment: Can you explain how the connection mechanism might relate to the problem I'm dealing with? Would have thought it would not matter that I've created a session object. 

I can't show the session object anyway. Sensitive information.

Comment: Look, I appreciate you're trying to help but seriously, I know the problem has nothing to do with creating a session ok. Right now all you are doing is wasting both our time. 

I do many many different remote operations. The problem is NOT comms related. Read the description of the problem again or stop wasting my time.